# Pronunciation of "I'd like" and "You've got"

Tags: pronunciation

I am not a native speaker so i wanted to ask this. When you say "You've gotta be careful" do you pronounce 'have' part and when you say "I'd like to..." do you say 'would' part?

Comment: In casual/informal/"sloppy" speech, many native speakers discard the auxiliary "have" completely in such constructions, but "would" is *at most* contracted to ***'d*** - it's never completely omitted.

Comment: For some readers, *gotta* (as opposed to the more careful *got to*) would be pronounced with a glottal stop.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people omit the "'ve" from "You've got to be careful" in 'folksy' dialects.  But in general, including it helps interpretation, and sounds proper.  The 'got to' already forces the perfect tense on you.

No one omits the "'d" from "I'd like to" because "I like to" means something slightly different.  The former, with the 'would', refers to a specific wish, present at the time of speaking, to do something in the future (or in imagination).  The other, without the 'would', refers to a general trend, when there may be no specific wish at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can, but it is not necessary. I, personally, do not prefer the use of contractions. This is more of a matter of dialect than the entire language. You can leave out the entire word "have" in "you've" and pronounce it "yoov" or just say "you have". The same applies for "I'd". You can either say "Ide" or "I would".

Answer (score 1):

> "You've gotta be careful"

If it's written that way then you would usually read it that way. However, in a dialog, you could do either way and be correct.

**Note:** "gotta" is slang and the proper term would be "got to", "have to", "need to". (The last two examples wouldn't use the contraction. ex. "You have to be careful")

> You've got to be careful